# display two values in one line sentence

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("projectdata.csv")
def dispOceania(df):
    year=df["Year"]
    oceania=df["Oceania"]
    print(f"In {year}, export to Oceania was {oceania:.2f}")
```

The error is `unsupported format string passed to Series.__format`

```
Year,America,Asia,Europe,Oceania,Africa,European Union,,,
1995,26233.5,50863.1,17311.4,3019.1,1045.6,16533.2,,,
1996,27906.7,53824.3,17835.1,3093.8,928.9,17011.4,,,
1997,29192.7,55016.1,19381,2997.8,947.6,18789.1,,,
1998,30407.5,50197.3,21386.8,2938.3,987.7,20875.6,,,
```

Comment: `year` and `oceania` are entire columns of data. Are you trying to print all the data for each row or just a sample of it?

Comment: .. `print(oceania)` to see what it really entails ... it is not a single number - this is _debugging_ you can easily use yourself. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: all the data of year and oceania

Comment: Could you include a sample of the dataframe in the form of a dictionary?

Comment: when i print(oceania) all data are shown

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`.

Here it shows for Year and Oceania with `dummy values`. But the procedure is similar.

```py
df[['Year', 'Oceania']].apply(lambda x: print(f"In {x[0]}, export to Oceania was {x[1]:.2f}"), axis=1)
```

```
In 1995.0, export to Oceania was 26233.50
In 1996.0, export to Oceania was 27906.70
In 1997.0, export to Oceania was 29192.70
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dispOceania(df):
    year=df["Year"]
    oceania=df["Oceania"]
    for y,oc in zip(year,oceania):
        print(f"In {y}, export to oceania was {oc:.2f}")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)